# Looper Handler Example

Tags: android

I was trying to understand the looper and handler in android, but got stuck with the example written.
What I am trying to do is, add a looper to the thread, to make thread running continuously in run() method. Then post messages or runnables to the hanlder thread.

```
public class HLClass extends Thread {
        Handler mHandler;
        @Override
        public void run() {
            super.run();
            Looper.prepare();
            mHandler = new Handler(){
                @Override
                public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                    super.handleMessage(msg);
                    Log.d("HLClass","In Handler, Msg = "+msg.arg1);
                }
            };
            Looper.loop();
        }
    }
```

This is how I am trying to call handler:

```
HLClass hlc = new HLClass();
          hlc.start();
          Message m = hlc.mHandler.obtainMessage();
          m.arg1 = 10;
          hlc.mHandler.sendMessage(m);
```

Error:

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.os.Message android.os.Handler.obtainMessage()' on a null object reference

Here, what really I am trying to understand that, how I can attach a handler to thread and then post message from any other thread
How can I safely post Message or Runnable to handler without error.

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: @tyczj What I am trying to do is, add a looper to the thread, to make thread running continuously in run() method. Then post messages or runnables to the hanlder thread.

Answer (score 2):

A Handler is a component that can be attached to a thread and then made to perform some action on that thread via simple messages or Runnable tasks. It works in conjunction with another component, Looper, which is in charge of message processing in a particular thread.

When a Handler is created, it can get a Looper object in the constructor, which indicates which thread the handler is attached to. If you want to use a handler attached to the main thread, you need to use the looper associated with the main thread by calling Looper.getMainLooper().

In this case, to update the UI from a background thread, you can create a handler attached to the UI thread, and then post an action as a Runnable:

```
Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
    handler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // update the ui from here                
        }
    });
```

This approach is a lot better than the first one, but there is an even simpler way to do this…

Comment: Thank you @ Zhao Lin. But here, what really I am trying to understand that, how I can attach a handler to thread and then post message from any other thread.

Comment: Hi, @Amol K, I understand what you want now. Then your code is almost done. The error is that you accessed mHandler before it is initialized.

Comment: Hi, @Amol K, I have added another answer for code implementation.

Answer (score 2):

You can try following code for sending message.

```
final HLClass hlc = new HLClass();
hlc.start();
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
     public void run() {
            Message m = hlc.mHandler.obtainMessage();
            m.arg1 = 10;
            hlc.mHandler.sendMessage(m);
     }
}, 300);
```

Comment: Hi, @Zhao Lin, thanks , it worked. But still not clear why we need to create new Handler and post runnable. Because before using the handler, the code was running in the same thread id as run() method of new Handler is running. Could you please help to understand.

Comment: Hi, @Amol K. The "hlc.start()" does not directly run "run()". It only sends message to run. The run() function will be running on another thread after receiving request. In your code, only requesting start and used handler. So in timeframe, functions below start() will run before than run() in thread. If you access handler from another request like button click after running the function which contains start(), it will work without using handler.

Comment: Even adding little delay after start() also worked. Thanks.

Comment: Yes. it will work with only little delays. If my question help you to solve, i hope you will make this answer as marked. Thanks